# selecting specific part of data set

Tags: data, filtering, dataset, data-structures

I have data set in form {section, Arcangale ,X,Y, type}. Section is the number between 1 to 3 (1,2,3), Arcangale is number change from 0 to 1 something like this (0.0176575), x and y are coordinate (example:(1685.34, 1319.77)), type is number between 1 to 15. I want to separate/select this data set base on the section and type. for example first I want to get all of the data that section==1 and the select base on the type as example type==12. At end I want to have (Arcangale ,X,Y) coordinate for all of the data that have (for example) section==1 and type==12.

Comment: Take a look at [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html). For example: ``Cases[list, {1, _, _, _, 12}]`` or ``Cases[list, {1, aa_, x_, y_, 12} :> {x, y}]``.

Comment: Maybe [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) (which returns associations) or [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) (which returns nested lists).

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html).

With example `data`

```
n = 200;
SeedRandom[987];
data =
  Transpose@
   {
    RandomInteger[{1, 3}, n]
    , RandomReal[1, n]
    , Sequence @@ 
     Partition[RandomInteger[{130000, 170000}, 2 n]/100., n]
    , RandomInteger[{1, 15}, n]
    };
Short@data
```

> ```
> {{3,0.932128,1393.48,1348.83,5},<<198>>,{2,0.526802,1503.34,1660.94,1}}
> ```

Then you can `Select` `data` directly using index positions with [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

```
Select[
  data,
  #[[{1, -1}]] == {1, 12} &
  ][[All, {3, 4}]]
```

> ```
> {{1545.15, 1531.7}, {1668.49, 1364.58}, {1312.75, 1566.74}, 
>  {1331., 1478.98}, {1448.64, 1390.46}, {1587.36, 1367.59}, 
>  {1360.02, 1694.58}, {1570.55, 1480.11}, {1401.99, 1472.49}}
> ```

To use named columns instead of indices an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) can be constructed with [`AssociationThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html).

```
colname = {"Section", "Arcangale", "X", "Y", "Type"};
assocList = AssociationThread[colname, #] & /@ data;
Short@assocList
```

> ```
> {<|Section->3,Arcangale->0.932128,X->1393.48,Y->1348.83,Type->5|>,<<198>>,<|Section->2,<<3>>,Type->1|>}
> ```

Then

```
res1 = Query[
   Select[#Section == 1 && #Type == 12 &]
   , {"X", "Y"}
   ]@assocList
```

> ```
> {<|X->1545.15,Y->1531.7|>,<|X->1668.49,Y->1364.58|>,<|X->1312.75,Y->1566.74|>, 
>  <|X->1331.,Y->1478.98|>,<|X->1448.64,Y->1390.46|>,<|X->1587.36,Y->1367.59|>,
>  <|X->1360.02,Y->1694.58|>,<|X->1570.55,Y->1480.11|>,<|X->1401.99,Y->1472.49|>}
> ```

Use [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) for only the values.

```
Values@res1
```

List of associations are good but memory hungry for tabular data. If your data is large enough you can use [`ResourceFunction["TableSet"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TableSet) for named column tabular data with less memory that list of associations.

```
tsdata = ResourceFunction["TableSet"][colname, data]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
Query[
  Select[#Section == 1 && #Type == 12 &]
  , {#X, #Y} &
  ]@tsdata
```

> ```
> {{1545.15, 1531.7}, {1668.49, 1364.58}, {1312.75, 1566.74}, 
>  {1331., 1478.98}, {1448.64, 1390.46}, {1587.36, 1367.59}, 
>  {1360.02, 1694.58}, {1570.55, 1480.11}, {1401.99, 1472.49}}
> ```

Notice about 4.5 times less memory needed than for list of associations.

```
ByteCount /@ {assocList, tsdata}
```

> ```
> {168064, 36640}
> ```

Hope this helps.